# Eclipse MTJ: How to archive all the classes into JAR even the class not referenced by MIDlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, midlet, mtj

I am using the Eclipse 3.5.2 with Mobile Tool Java plug-in ver. 1.0.1.
I found IF the class not referenced by MIDlet then this class will not be archived into the .jar file.
Does anybody know how to do that for archive all the classes under the MIDlet project even the class is not referenced by MIDlet?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those class to `resource`.